# CS50 Problem Set 2: Substitution - Segmentation fault (core dumped) - if (strlen(key) == 0)

Tags: c, cs50

Why am I getting `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` as a terminal output? It is caused by the second `if` statement.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string key = argv[1];

    if (strlen(key) != 26)
    {
        printf("Key must contain 26 characters.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (strlen(key) == 0)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to check whether argc is equal to 2.

Comment: The first line in `main` in this program should check if `argc` is at least `2`

Comment: It can be caused by `strlen(key)` because `key` can `NULL`. First you must check `if(argc > 1)` before executing anything else.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `string key = argv[1];`, what exactly do you expect this to mean? How many things do you think will be in `argv`, and why? Thus, will `argv[1]` always succeed? What would happen if it fails? Can you think of a way to check whether `argv` has enough elements? (Hint: when you write `int main(int argc, string argv[])`, what is the purpose of `argc`?)

Comment: @TedLyngmo the first line is OK, the next is not. The `argv[]` array has a `NULL` sentinel.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah, it'll be a null pointer if `argc==1` but it's still a pointless initialization.

Comment: @TedLyngmo sorry it was a strict observation.

Comment: Other stacks are a lot tighter about what goes down in comment. Here, there can be a lot of supplementary information for the asker.

Answer (score 0):

Just like it was said in the comments, you need to first verify if there's a second argument, or else it don't work, to verify this you can use the `argc` variable, it stores the amount of `args`.

So your if becomes like this:

```c
if (argc != 2) // verify arg quantity
{
    printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
    return 1;
}
else if (strlen(argv[1]) != 26) // verify arg size
{
    printf("Key must contain 26 characters.\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Also remember that you need to return `1` and not `-1`